# Where can I find the problem by Lagarias?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, riemann-hypothesis, arithmetic-functions

Jeffrey Lagarias proved, unconditionally, that:
$$
\sigma(n)<H_n+2\exp(H_n)\log(H_n)\qquad n>1
$$

This was posed as a problem in:

- J. C. Lagarias, *Problem 10949: A generous bound for divisor sums*, American Math. Monthly **109** no 6 (2002) 569, doi:[10.2307/2695448](https://doi.org/10.2307/2695448)

(**edit:** with solution given in AMM **111** no 3 (2004), 264–265, doi:[10.2307/4145148](https://doi.org/10.2307/4145148))

Where can I find this problem? Or, any other links that shows how the inequality has been derived would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I will also accept the answer if anyone can outline the steps, how Lagarias  derived his criterion.

Comment: It's not a paper. It's a problem Jeff submitted to the Monthly, and you have the citation for the issue and page where the solution was published. What's the problem?

Comment: The Monthly is available through JSTOR https://www.jstor.org/

Comment: I can't find the solution. just the problem 10949

Comment: In **Equivalents of the Riemann Hypothesis: Volume 1: Arithmetic Equivalents -- Kevin Broughan**  is mentioned, does anyone know if it is developed in this book?

Comment: You likely were looking at the monthly issue in 2002 (which solely states the problem). The solution can be found in the 2004 issue found [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4145148?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Comment: Tks @Mark  your link led me to the solution and looking further I found the key article: https://www.emis.de/journals/NSJOM/Papers/07/NSJOM_07_017_022.pdf

Comment: Why is there an 'also' in "Lagarias *also* proved unconditionally …" in the first sentence of your question?

Comment: it was just in case someone wanted to develop the idea. but with the help of @Mark it is no longer necessary. Tks

Comment: Why was the whole question edited out?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own questions.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use [Ivic's inequality](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266167796_Two_inequalities_for_the_sum_of_divisors_functions)

$\sigma(n)<2.59n \log \log n, n \ge 7$

Then $H_n>\log n +\gamma$ so $e^{H_N}>e^{\gamma}n$ and $\log H_n > \log \log n$ for $n \ge 3$ hence:

$2\exp(H_n)\log(H_n)>2e^{\gamma}n \log \log n>2.59 n \log \log n > \sigma(n), n \ge 7$ and check the cases $n=2,...,6$ by hand

Comment: Thank you @Conrad

Comment: happy to be of help